# JQuery jScrollPane reinitialise

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

I'm using the JQuery plugin jScrollPane

I'm intialising it as follows.. It works initially but when I try and change the settings and reinitialise it it doesnt work properly it kindof flickers and then returns to it's previous state, any ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var api = $('.viewer').jScrollPane().data('jsp');
     api.reinitialise({
         showArrows: true
     }); 
});
```

Here is my test example

http://www.jsfiddle.net/VxYdJ/

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is a [known issue](https://github.com/vitch/jScrollPane/issues/#issue/24) with jScrollPane.  You could modify the source code as one commenter describes in the link above:

```
reinitialise: function(s)
{
    s = $.extend({}, settings, s);
    initialise(s);
},
```

That seems to fix the problem: http://www.jsfiddle.net/pNvky/ (The ton of code up front is just the modified plugin)

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker i have an error saying that settings is not defined any idea?

Answer (score 5):

i had the same problems with the reinitialisation of jsp. i could solve it with this workaround.

destroy …

```
$("#some > img").click(function() {
    var container = $('.scroll-pane-arrows');
    var api = container.data('jsp');
        api.destroy();

   … calculate width or similar
```

… and build it up later on:

```
$('.scroll-pane-arrows').jScrollPane({
    showArrows: true,
    arrowScrollOnHover: true,
    arrowButtonSpeed: 5,
    autoReinitialise: true
});
```

Comment: I had to resort to this workaround as well with api.reinitialise() working only sporadically... even with edits to the source code as above. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you!! This helped a lot. I was struggling with this for a couple hours.